# Disable seeking in mediaelement.js

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, dom-events, mediaelement.js

I'm working on MediaElements.js to play some videos with subtitles.

I'm trying to disable the seeking inside the videos without hiding the progress bar.

I tried to add an `eventListener` based on seeked event but it fails and starts an infinite loop. I think this is related with the functions *rail.

This is my code (fails):

```
            // event handler
            mediaElement.addEventListener('seeked', function(e) {           
                mediaElement.setCurrentTime(0);
               mediaElement.play();


            }, true);
```

Does anyone know how can I do it?

Comment: I think the answer you are looking for is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958190/mediaelement-js-prevent-seek-forward-allow-seek-backwards/18275214#18275214

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mediaelement.js - Prevent Seek Forward / Allow Seek Backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958190/mediaelement-js-prevent-seek-forward-allow-seek-backwards)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you can cancel an event by calling [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation) and returning false from the event listener.

As long as the event listener is triggered before the actual seeking takes place, this should theoretically work:

```
mediaElement.addEventListener('seeked', function(e) {           
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}, true);
```