# mediaelement.js - Prevent Seek Forward / Allow Seek Backwards

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

Can you please give me an idea or sample that I can prevent seek forward to the seeking bar but will allow to seek backwards?

This is what I found but it keeps on a loop:

```
media.addEventListener('seeked', function(e) {           
    // player.setCurrentTime(0);
    // player.play();
}, true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i did was this: Inside the uncompressed version of mediaelement library find a row:
**media.setCurrentTime(newTime);**

Add above the previous line: 
**if ( newTime <= media.currentTime )**

Eventually you have:

```
if ( newTime <= media.currentTime )
media.setCurrentTime(newTime);
```

which means that if the time to be seeked is lower or equal to the player's current time
then allow seeking.

Answer (score 4):

I recently had the same requirement.

But didn't really want to modify the source file.

Here's another way of doing it without modifying the source:

```
  var _player = $("#my_video_1")[0].player; //<-- get the reference to the player

  old = _player.media.setCurrentTime; //<-- store the native setCurrentTime temporarily

  _player.media.setCurrentTime = function(time) { //<-- override it with our own method
      if(time <= this.currentTime){
          old.apply(this,[time]); //<-- call the stored method if our conditions are met
      }
  };
```